# Create lists based on list of non-adjacent indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list of indices (example below) and I want to define a function that given such an input i.e.,

`a=np.array([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,11,12,13])`

will return the bounds of the subsets of adjacent indices, for instance above

`result=np.array([[1,4],[6,8],[11,13]])`

Does anyone know of an efficient algorithm to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: whats the key for "adjacent indices"?

Comment: just that their values are seperated by 1 unit. for instance in the example, 6 is not next to 4 so it should starts a new set, and so on

Comment: in first two rows you want to have 3 elements, and [11,13] there are only 2 elements, why?

Comment: @rozumir 1:4 is a consecutive run of numbers, so he wants the start and end only. Same for 6:8 and 11:13.

Comment: Exactly sorry, consecutive is a better word! thanks

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks!